# The Use of Sound in Mathematics.

Tags: self-learning, education

*I'm not sure that this question is appropriate here. There's a good chance it's too opinion-based. If that's the case, I'm sorry.*

I was sat in a research seminar recently and wondered whether it'd be tacky if the speaker made the mathematics in his presentation somehow audible (in a non-trivial sense).

I've been tempted to write a programme or something ever since, that'd attach all the bells & whistles to a given symbol-heavy proof. I picture something like a beamer presentation where each relevant slide makes a noise once it's called, so that any patterns in the equations (or whatever) really leap out at the audience. If used sparingly and with [*taste*](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/1954944/), I suppose it could be quite effective.

$\color{red}{\text{The }}\color{green}{\text{use }}\color{blue}{\text{of }}\color{magenta}{\text{colour }}$, $\Large{\text{font sizes}}$, *italics*, etc., are certainly effective on me, so why not sound?

In studying Mathematics alone, too, especially with dry, dense proofs, I have tried making small noises. It is a bit silly, yeah, but the odd "pop" for certain substitutions can be really handy. If anything, it makes things less dry . . .

So here's my question:

> How best does one use sound in the study and/or presentation of Mathematics?

Again, I'm sorry if this is too opinion-based.

Comment: I could see this having a lot of application to making math audiobooks a useful thing.

Comment: Seems more like a question for [Cognition S.E.](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) than opinion based, if you ask me.

Comment: If a given music or rythm makes you remembering a theorem or a proof or whatever, it is very good for you.

Comment: Now I'm imagining composing a full orchestral score for your talk, with a Wagner-esque leitmotif for each lemma...

Comment: @NateEldredge This is especially applicable if the talk is about [rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen).

Comment: What a delightful questions.  What is the true music of our mathematics.  Most would suggest something in the style of Bach, while my personal experience sounds more like Schoenberg.

Comment: I've voted to close. I think this is more appropriate in [Mathematics Educators S.E.](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) or, as @GitGud suggested, Cognition S.E. **I'm sorry.** Please migrate this question accordingly :)

Comment: @Shaun: while I agree that the questions may be more on-topic at Math Educators or Cognition, now that the question is closed here, I would encourage you let it be and instead ask a new copy over at one of the two websites your mentioned. I say so because there are certain disadvantages to migrated questions (if the community there decides that it is not on-topic in its current form, you don't get a chance to edit to clarify, unlike in the case of "normal" questions). And you may want to re-write the question a bit to make it better for the audiences there.

Comment: Also, if you do ask it on those other sites, feel free to leave a comment here linking to the other copy. Some of the shared audience between the two sites would surely be interested.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you. I'll post a copy of the question on one of those sites later today. (I'm a little busy at the moment.)

Comment: Okay, I've put a [copy](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/the-use-of-sound-in-mathematics) on Mathematics Educators S.E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mentor, a delightfully eccentric mathematician, uses sounds quite often. I remember, when he introduced difference sets to a bunch of people, he gave one of the defining equations of algebraic design theory by making a little popping noise with his tongue after he was finished writing it on the blackboard. In the next lecture, when he wanted his students to remember the equation, he allowed about 30 seconds of silence before he made the popping noise. At least a dozen hands shot up, whereas before this sound, there was only one (me). I consider this effective.

I also remember seeing a colloquium talk where the speaker made annoying sounds that contributed nothing. He did this incessantly, throughout the entire talk. I consider this ineffective.

Thus, my experience-based guidelines might look like this:

1. Sound is a good pedagogical tool.
2. Use sound sparingly, and only to emphasize recurring and important points.
3. Make the sounds mildly entertaining and particularly memorable.
4. Stop making noises if your audience displays distinct signs of discomfort from it.